# Add shaded region to ggplot with unscaled x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the data provided at bottom, I would like to add one shaded region to the left and a different shaded region to the right of the vertical line in each facet in the following ggplot. Because the x-axis in each facet is simply a unique label, I'm struggling with this application as I have no clear xmin/xmax to provide.

So my question is, is it possible to add shaded regions to each facet in plots without continuous x-axes?

[image]

```
> dput(WF_postdist_melt)
structure(list(Species = c("ABDU", "AMCO", "AMWI", "BUFF", "BWTE", 
"CANG", "CNV", "COGO", "GADW", "GWTE", "HOME", "MALL", "MERG", 
"NOPI", "NSHO", "REDH", "RNDU", "SCAUP", "SNGO", "SWAN", "WODU", 
"ABDU", "AMCO", "AMWI", "BUFF", "BWTE", "CANG", "CNV", "COGO", 
"GADW", "GWTE", "HOME", "MALL", "MERG", "NOPI", "NSHO", "REDH", 
"RNDU", "SCAUP", "SNGO", "SWAN", "WODU", "ABDU", "AMCO", "AMWI", 
"BUFF", "BWTE", "CANG", "CNV", "COGO", "GADW", "GWTE", "HOME", 
"MALL", "MERG", "NOPI", "NSHO", "REDH", "RNDU", "SCAUP", "SNGO", 
"SWAN", "WODU", "ABDU", "AMCO", "AMWI", "BUFF", "BWTE", "CANG", 
"CNV", "COGO", "GADW", "GWTE", "HOME", "MALL", "MERG", "NOPI", 
"NSHO", "REDH", "RNDU", "SCAUP", "SNGO", "SWAN", "WODU", "ABDU", 
"AMCO", "AMWI", "BUFF", "BWTE", "CANG", "CNV", "COGO", "GADW", 
"GWTE", "HOME", "MALL", "MERG", "NOPI", "NSHO", "REDH", "RNDU", 
"SCAUP", "SNGO", "SWAN", "WODU", "ABDU", "AMCO", "AMWI", "BUFF", 
"BWTE", "CANG", "CNV", "COGO", "GADW", "GWTE", "HOME", "MALL", 
"MERG", "NOPI", "NSHO", "REDH", "RNDU", "SCAUP", "SNGO", "SWAN", 
"WODU"), Coefficient = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), class = "factor", .Label = c("AmeliaIntercept", 
"AmeliaWLCoef", "AmeliaRCCoef", "BUGSIntercept", "BUGSWLCoef", 
"BUGSRCCoef")), Mean = c(-4802, -4805, -4800, 30050, -4801, 36090, 
-4807, -4802, -4803, -4803, -128800, -4802, 43430, -4787, -4801, 
-4802, -4802, -4805, -4803, -4801, -4800, 2505, -1437, 20, -1543, 
271, -1260, 242, 5609, 778, 465, 1113, 1187, -364, 1469, 754, 
376, 573, -1539, 9, 924, 261, 2625, 1440, -242.9, -1268, 34.87, 
-217.8, 503.5, 4765, 1026, -185.1, -591.4, -90.39, 273.3, -612.9, 
-7.29, 197.2, 16.38, 519.6, 636.3, 116.9, -812.5, 16250, 16260, 
16250, -50800, 16260, 2496, 16240, 16250, 16260, 16250, 61630, 
16250, 51830, 16270, 16250, 16260, 16250, 16260, 16250, 16250, 
16250, 2749, -1690, 157, -336, 183, 347, -54, 5231, 203, -700, 
-771, 1074, -677, 987, 663, 227, 321, -948, -740, 703, 81, 2688, 
-554.9, -252.8, 1183, -103.9, -1333, 1336, 5160, -498.8, 280.1, 
-770, -233.8, -183, -597.4, -146.1, 97.26, 139.7, 295.5, 137.5, 
85.01, -82.17), LowerCI = c(-5091, -5046, -5087, 21390, -5089, 
25700, -5135, -5089, -5087, -5093, -165800, -5092, 31220, -5066, 
-5090, -5088, -5091, -5095, -5102, -5091, -5092, 981, -1444, 
-58, -1545, -128, -1260, 235, 3964, 723, 411, 1113, 645, -365, 
1461, 307, 34, 52, -1621, -161, 483, 208, 738.3, 1430, -297.2, 
-1269, -378.2, -218, 495.4, 2734, 619.1, -245.3, -594.4, -543.9, 
268, -627.8, -500.7, -273.3, -680.2, 236.6, 500.6, -426.2, -939, 
16010, 15870, 16010, -71570, 16010, -1601, 15960, 16010, 16010, 
16020, 49940, 16010, 42920, 16060, 16010, 16010, 16010, 16020, 
16010, 16010, 16010, 1200, -1697, 106, -337, -82, 347, -59, 3607, 
130, -834, -771, 749, -677, 980, 386, -104, 2, -1038, -915, 358, 
23, 741, -561.7, -308.5, 1183, -512.3, -1336, 1316, 3280, -559.5, 
216.5, -793.4, -720.1, -185.1, -607.8, -456.5, -287.4, -239.5, 
195.7, 46.58, -417.2, -140.6), UpperCI = c(-4502, -4511, -4505, 
40620, -4499, 48580, -4494, -4501, -4505, -4499, -97720, -4501, 
57960, -4299, -4508, -4501, -4500, -4510, -4509, -4503, -4501, 
4051, -1428, 88, -1542, 504, -1259, 251, 7319, 825, 512, 1114, 
1727, -364, 1476, 1146, 734, 1134, -1480, 153, 1366, 322, 4470, 
1447, -185.6, -1267, 622.4, -217.6, 513.4, 6706, 1619, -117.2, 
-585.9, 646.6, 279.7, -603.1, 572.2, 578, 573.9, 772, 743.1, 
605.5, -693.7, 16500, 16550, 16510, -33780, 16510, 6005, 16480, 
16510, 16510, 16520, 75220, 16500, 62640, 16560, 16510, 16510, 
16510, 16510, 16500, 16510, 16500, 4137, -1683, 206, -335, 468, 
348, -45, 6914, 273, -569, -770, 1363, -676, 993, 930, 566, 666, 
-861, -572, 938, 119, 4485, -549, -209.9, 1185, 265.6, -1330, 
1352, 7023, -446.9, 404.1, -764.4, 145.4, -181.7, -586.1, 234.3, 
480.2, 590.2, 396.4, 224.7, 706.7, -16.03), Imputation_Method = c("Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", 
"Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "Amelia", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", 
"BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS", "BUGS"), CoefficientType = c("Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", 
"WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", 
"WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", 
"RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", 
"RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", 
"RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", 
"WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", 
"WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", "WLCoef", 
"WLCoef", "WLCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", 
"RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", 
"RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", "RCCoef", 
"RCCoef", "RCCoef")), .Names = c("Species", "Coefficient", "Mean", 
"LowerCI", "UpperCI", "Imputation_Method", "CoefficientType"), row.names = c(NA, 
-126L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001a0788>)
```

ggplot construction:

```
ggplot(data=WF_postdist_melt,aes(x=Species,y=Mean,colour=CoefficientType,
                                 group=Coefficient)) + 
  # geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf,xmax=0,ymin=-10000,ymax=10000)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LowerCI,ymax=UpperCI),size=1.25,width=1,
                position=pd) +
  geom_point(position=pd,size=1.5,shape=21,fill="white") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  ylab("Waterfowl Model Posterior Estimate") + xlab(NULL) +
  scale_colour_hue(name="Parameter",
                   breaks=c("AmeliaIntercept","AmeliaWLCoef",
                            "AmeliaRCCoef","BUGSIntercept","BUGSWLCoef",
                            "BUGSRCCoef"),
                   labels=c("Intercept (Amelia)",
                            "Water Level Coefficient (Amelia)",
                            "Rice Cover Coefficient (Amelia)",
                            "Intercept (BUGS)",
                            "Water Level Coefficient (BUGS)",
                            "Rice Cover Coefficient (BUGS)"),
                   l=40) +
  facet_wrap(~Species,scales="free") + theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
    axis.text=element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
    legend.title=element_text(face="bold")
  )
```

Comment: A categorical x axis is plotted on integers.  With only a single value per facet, your x axis labels are positioned at 1 and each x axis goes from .5 to 1.5.  You can add shaded areas/rectangles based on this coordinate system.

Comment: That information satisfies my curiosity greatly. Unfortunately, when I try including `geom_rect(aes(xmin=0.5,xmax=1,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf))`, I get `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Comment: Take it out of `aes`.

Comment: Bingo. If you submit that as an answer, I will accept. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A categorical x axis is plotted on integer values starting with 1, which you can refer to when adding, e.g., rectangles to denote certain areas.

As you have a single x value per facet, each x axis label is centered at the value 1 and the x axis of each facet goes from .5 to 1.5.

To add rectangles to each facet, one to the left and one to the right of your axis label and grid line, you can use the x axis integer coordinate system and add something like:

```
geom_rect(xmin = .5, xmax = 1, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
geom_rect(xmin = 1, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "blue")
```